# Why am I not seeing Core Web Vitals data in the Synthetics - Browser Test Performance dashboard in Datadog?

Tags: datadog, core-web-vitals, rum, datadog-dashboard

After creating a synthetic browser test for a page that has Datadog's RUM javascript capturing data, I expected to see the `Synthetic test web performance` section of the `Synthetics - Browser Test Performance dashboard` display LCP and CLS data for the specified `TestID`. However, after letting the browser test run for a few days, I am not seeing anything.

Is there anything else that I need to enable or configure?

[image: Synthetics - Browser Test Performance]

**Update:**

After seeing Keith's answer, I checked `Collect RUM data for this test` in the test recording page and now I'm seeing the data I was expecting.

[image: Collect RUM data for test]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CLS and LCP widgets present on the Synthetics - Browser Test Performance dashboard do rely on RUM data.

Screenshot of the query: https://a.cl.ly/6quNQQbO
RUM can be injected via the recording section of the browser test steps!

That being said, they can view CLS without leveraging RUM, using the synthetics.browser.step.cumulative_layout_shift metric.

Docs: https://docs.datadoghq.com/synthetics/metrics/#overview